# Excel Remove FTP Login

Tags: excel, ftp, disconnect

I've inherited an excel spreadsheet that was once connected to an FTP site. I would like this removed. How do I removed the connection so the spreadsheet does not ask to connect every time the spreadsheet is opened? [FTP - Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG1ZF.png)

Comment: I haven't dealt with FTP links, but try Edit Links to see if it is listed.  In Excel 2016, Edit Links is found at Data-Connections-Edit Links.  Sorry, if you have earlier version, I don't remember where it used to be.

Comment: Thanks, but that was the first place I looked! :)

Comment: Did you run Document Inspector on it?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me.. I'll copy all the data (sheet by sheet) to a fresh new file.. and save it saperately. Hope that helps. (:

Comment: That's my last and final resort to make it go away!